# Access from iframe to iframe - Angular Scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I would like to test my app. To do this, I choose Angular Scenario. I have iframe into iframe. And i have to get access to second iframe. But Angular Scenario see only first iframe - Angular Scenario don't want to go inside (I don't know why...). Construction of my webapp (in the simplest):

```
<head> ... </head>
<html> //some code//    
<iframe id="iframeOne" .... src=".." ... >

   <html><body><div> <iframe id="iframeTwo" ... src="...">  
      <html> ...... some page </html>
   </iframe></div></body></html> </iframe>
</html>
```

And here is my problem and question. In angular Scenario I can't get to "frameTwo". 
When I printed content of `$document.element()` i saw iframeOne byt without element iframeTwo. It looked like:

`<iframe ..... ></iframe>`

Can you tell me is it possible to get access to iframeTwo? It is very important for me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can get a reference to the iframe using `document.getElementById` then use the element for access.